# Run a Conditional Using PHP Version

Tags: php

So my goal right now is to detect the user's PHP version (not an issue), and then run an if else based on it

So if I write something like this:

```
if (PHP => 5.3){
// call a function anonymously
}
else {
// if user does not have 5.3, this else block disables the feature. 
}
```

the issue I'm having is I want to use PHP's anonymous functions if the user has 5.3 or greater (since they were introduced in PHP 5.3) and an alternative if they have an older version. The problem is, of course, that if a user has PHP 5.2.17 for instance, that while that if statement will never evaluate as true, a fatal error will be thrown for syntax since the anonymous function call looks like a syntax error to PHP 5.2.17

Is there a way to do something like the above? The only work around I've found is to put the stuff in the if in a new file, and the stuff in the else in another, and do something like this:

```
$version = '5.2';//user's current version cut to the nearest x.y, ex 5.3, 5.4, 5.5
// Remove the period here, so we have 5.2
require 'function'.$version.'.php';
```

Now this will work fine, since function53.php will never be loaded for a 5.2 user. However it's not ideal to have to use separate files.

After reading the comment's to Ales's quesiton, something like this:

```
if ($version > '5.3'){
// require one file
}
else{
// require another
}
```

Will not work. PHP's compiler will run both files on compilation checking for syntax errors before execution and throw the error I'm trying to avoid. The only way for the file method to work is to dynamically pick a file based on version number. This requires a seperate file for every x.y release from PHP 4 and 5. Not ideal.

On Alex's answer, it works fine. We're talking one line of eval (required to hide the anonymous function call), versus the proposed tons of files.

Comment: [version_compare()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php) ?

Comment: Way, *way* too much work. You're seriously going to write *two copies* of all your code, just to take advantage of new syntax, when the old syntax *works fine* in both versions?

Comment: Do you really want to duplicate code for this? You should have *one* implementation of that function in the syntax that the lowest PHP version you want to support can handle. It'll work the same, you shouldn't rewrite it as closure *as well* just because you can.

Comment: @meagar, Yes. In my case, I need to use anonymous functions for what I need to do. In the case they don't have them, I just disable the feature.

Comment: @deceze I'm writing a plugin for WordPress. I can't be sure that all users will have my imposed minimum version of PHP. WordPress still supports pre-5.3 PHP. Its not duplicate code. If they don't have the minimum required version, they don't get to use that functionality.

Comment: If you are checking for versions that introduce a whole new syntax, you have to keep that away from the php parser where it isn't supported, either in separate files or by using ``eval``.

Comment: @mzedeler Exactly what I did in my answer below, which was downvoted twice for no reason, lol

Comment: @AlexColeman Yeah I don't know why they did. Seems people aren't reading the question. Upvoted it

Comment: It should be noted, that while this question is flagged as related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360577/is-it-possible-to-switch-in-php-based-on-version they are fundamentally different questions. This one is attempting to prevent syntax errors on compilation. That one is trying to simply run an if else based on version.

Comment: A code sample of the actual version dependent code would be really helpful. There's probably a simple solution which works on all PHP versions, or at least we could suggest something appropriate for the situation. If the code snippet is so small that several files are "overkill", show us what we're talking about.

Comment: BTW, since apparently you don't believe me that conditional includes *are* conditional: http://3v4l.org/pLEet You have some problem in your code that makes the conditional always true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just eval the code, which compiles on the fly.

```
$res = -1
if (PHP => 5.3){
    eval('$res = [some advanced PHP 5.3 fast code]');
}
else {
    $res = [some basic PHP 4 code still supported by 5.3, just deprecated];
    eval('$res = [some real rudimentary PHP 4 code no longer supported at all in 5.3]');
}
$res = $res + 1;
echo $res;

if (PHP => 5.3){
    eval('$res = [some more advanced PHP 5.3 fast code]');
}
else {
    $res = [some more basic PHP 4 code still supported by 5.3, just deprecated];
    eval('$res = [some more real rudimentary PHP 4 code no longer supported at all in 5.3]');
}
```

See how it would be a pain to include 50 different files this way, but eval's make it easy? There are regions in his file of big overlap, so he doesn't want to merely make two separate files, so instead he wants a way to run the two separate sections of code in the middle of his file a bunch of times.

Comment: @OneTrickPony "So my goal right now is to detect the user's PHP version (not an issue)," " fatal error will be thrown for syntax since the anonymous function call looks like a syntax error to PHP 5.2.17" his issue is not with detecting the veresion, but with getting syntax errors for the new block of code that doesn't work with old PHP. The solution is an eval, which will only give syntax errors once it is run (and it won't run for old versions). Please read the question before randomly downvoting...

Comment: @OneTrickPony No, please read what I wrote, I specifically said "however it's not ideal to have to use separate files."

Alex's solution seems to be what I'm looking for. Testing it right now.

Comment: @Chris I'd really stay away from writing any amount of code as string to `eval`, go with the separate file include instead!

Comment: @deceze Thats not ideal at all. I'd have to have 50 something files in that implementation. One for every PHP version. So your suggestion is to use like 51x more code?

Comment: @deceze / OneTrickPony Well if you want to avoid a cluttered file system where you have a file each time you want to switch PHP versions that you use, eval's are the way to go. It's a completely legitimate option. TBH, he should avoid switching versions like that entirely, but this is probably the best way to do it if he has to

Comment: @Chris Why would you need *50* files? Just a simple `if (/* version over 5.3 */) require 'functions_5.3.php';`.

Comment: @AlexColeman can you please quote any example for eval in above code which runs for 5.3 and for php 4.

Comment: @Chris: you only need two files: one for php 5.3+, and one 5.2.-5.3. No need for `eval` here (WP needs 5.2.4+ to run anyway)

Comment: @AlexColeman Yeah, I don't have a choice unfortunately. If it was up to me, the plugin wouldn't be run by users running old PHP versions, but I have to abide by the rules of the repository

Comment: @deceze Because he may have to do this 50 different times

Comment: @OneTrickPony see my answer above, this only shows one time but he has already stated multiple times that he needs to do this often.

Comment: @Nomi Which runs for both versions? So something basic like $test = 5;?

Comment: @Alex There aren't 50 different versions of PHP you need to support. At a maximum PHP 4, 5, 5.3, 5.4 and 5.5, depending on what features you need. That's 5 files max, most likely only really two for 5.3+ and 5.2-. And I'd still prefer 50 well named files than one long file with 50 unreadable evals.

Comment: @deceze That doesn't work. As mentioned prior, the compiler will run both blocks of code for syntax error prior to running. Therefore, both files will be included and the error will avoid. The only way to avoid it is to dynamically pick a filename based on version. Again 51 files.

Comment: @Chris I think this comment thread is completely going off the rails, it doesn't make sense anymore.

Comment: @AlexColeman what if we do have thousands of lines with calculations will eval handle that?

Comment: @deceze I have to support every x.y in PHP 4 and 5. Even still that's 12 files? We're talking about 1 eval line here. Since there's no eval needed for the part in the else, since it will work on older versions.

Comment: @deceze No, it makes perfect sense. Read the question and you'll understand.

Comment: @Nomi Yes, but that's not needed; I'm not suggesting we eval a whole file, just the small section where the two split for a second

Comment: @Chris Yes, in *your* code you have to use one file for every version. I'm saying you just check `if (/* PHP >= 5.3 */) include /* one file */ else /* include another file */`!

Comment: @deceze He is stating that there are sections of code which he wants to split, but then they rejoin after. I'll add an example

Comment: Well, if there are multiple code blocks he needs to include at various stages, then I'd say the problem is in the application design. And using `eval` to "fix" this is still not a good idea.

Comment: @OneTrickPony I already stated that yes, he should avoid doing it, but include is a worse solution. Why is eval not a good fix? Please elaborate on that. All of you keep saying "just include, eval sucks" for no apparent reason...

Comment: @deceze Again that does not work. Read the question, I explained why that does not work. Try running it. It will not work.

Comment: @OneTrickPony as explained in the question I'm trying to avoid one line of PHP code from being run. A single line of eval seems better than 12 files.

Comment: It's not because is "evil", but the use of this function is rarely needed. This is just another of those cases where it isn't. @Chris you should post your real code, that way you may get solutions to your real problem that is driving you to use `eval` to fix it

Comment: @OneTrickPony First of all, some idiot still has to remove their downvote or post a reason for it. Second of all, it simplifies the code a lot to have one eval for each small snippet where he switches versions as opposed to 2 files for each small snippet...

Comment: @AlexColeman right, it also worked for me. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
$version = explode('.', PHP_VERSION);
if ($version[0] > 5 || ($version[0] == 5 && $version[1] >= 3)) {
    //include with anonymous functions
    include 'file1.php';
} else {
    //include alternatives
    include 'file2.php';
}
```

Since you can't add php5-code directly in the code and you don't want to include a file there is a way to use `create_function()` where you put your code as a string, that is not pretty either, but could do the job for you.

Comment: This method was already suggested in the comments... Also, don't like it because it clutters file system

Comment: @Alex Well it is better than using eval + everywhere make comparison.

Comment: and it is the normal solution to use mulitple files for multiple versions if you dont have precompile conditions like in c and don´t want to compare on every call what to do.

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj Making comparisons is a completely invalid argument; both code snippets use this! And no, quite frankly it isn't. Eval works fine, as does include, eval just allows it to remain in one file

Comment: @luk2302 Maybe for the entire file, but he specifically asked for how to do it for little miniature snippets throughout his file, meaning he would have to include many files

Comment: @luk2302 I only need to avoid one line of code (a call to an anonymous function) as indicated in the question. This answer will not work, even fundamentally, as explained in the question.

Comment: @luk2302 No, you can't do that. That doesn't work! You can't just "use new features" like that without getting syntax errors... *facepalm*

Comment: @luk2302 Still won't work. Read the question, I explained why. That throws syntax errors if you try doing that.

Comment: @Chris I have tried inclusion example (make a parse error example) for  but did not get any error. However I am sure second inline way definitely gave error.

Comment: what about create_function(), not nice but would do the job

Comment: @luk2302 That is the **SAME** thing as I said, it's the same as an eval essentially!

Comment: Why are people still upvoting this question? The OP himself has already stated this is invalid, because he wants to do it multiple times which is a big mess if you need two files for each scenario

Answer (score 2):

For each feature, define one *function* or *class*. If you need version specific differences for these, create one file for each version. E.g.:

*features_5.3.php*

```
function foo() { ... }

function bar() { ... }
```

*features_5.2.php*

```
function foo() { ... }

function bar() { ... }
```

Then check once which version you're running on and include the appropriate file:

```
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '>=')) {
    require_once 'features_5.3.php';
} else {
    require_once 'features_5.2.php';
}
```

Then use your feature where needed:

```
foo();
```

For PHP versions which don't support those features, just make `foo()` a no-op; or maybe check if the feature is supported when you need to call it:

```
if (function_exists('foo'))
```

or set constants:

```
if (FEATURE_FOO_AVAILABLE) {
    foo();
}
```

Comment: This is a smart solution, I'll give it that, but it also makes it a pain; modifying variables from a function requires you to global them and stuff, which just makes everything get unnecessarily messy. But still kudos for this, smart idea, +1

Comment: I really can't tell if this is a troll or not. If you try running this, as explained in the question, both files will be run by PHP. Therefore, you'll get the errors.

Comment: @Chris **They will not!!** Conditional includes are conditional!

Comment: @Chris no, he's fine, the version compare checks which to include

Comment: @Alex It's the most manageable solution. If you need shared variables, use classes.

Comment: @deceze Eval seems more manageable though, doesn't require any globals or classes like that. Nothing wrong with eval's so long as you avoid user input into them

Comment: @Alex If it's one tiny snippet of code, maybe. But code tends to grow, and if you need to pass variables in and out of your eval snippets it's going to be a mess! Also, writing any amount of code as string is a mess either way.

Comment: @deceze The OP has already stated many times that it **is** one small snippet of code! Also, it's still pretty easy to share variables in evals, not in functions across files like that

Comment: @Alex Well, he's saying it's about the use of anonymous functions. I can't really imagine a snippet using an anonymous function so small that it won't be annoying to work with or not very useful when written as eval string. A real example would help here, admittedly.

Comment: @deceze Well anonymous functions that are only ran once are essentially eval's, right? Or am I missing something? - Wait. Who do you mean by "he"?

Comment: I'll go get a drink... This is the least productive discussion I've had in a while, since we're missing details and the OP keeps misunderstanding the suggestion of separate files. This question needs a lot more context to be productively discussed.